# Php: Set header for cookie attribute SameSite=None;Secure is not working at all

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, header, samesite

I know there is many solutions given regarding the same question but I tried all of them and none of them working at all.

I am tried following ways but none of them worked. My php version is 7.1 and Codeigniter framework I am using.

By setting header in index.php

`header('Set-Cookie: HttpOnly; SameSite=None;Secure');`

By setting in .htaccess

`Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=none"`

By setting in apache2 httpd.conf

`Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None"`

I have reviewed Chrmoe git updates, it says
`header('Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=bar; SameSite=None; Secure');`

I didn't get the option `cross-site-cookie=bar`. What will be value for it.

I also tried the same one but it didn't work at all.

Comment: _“I didn't get the option `cross-site-cookie=bar`”_ - that’s simply the name and value of the cookie …

Comment: I have tried. I am setting my cookie value and name but it doesn't working

Comment: I just tested it, under PHP 7.2, and it works as expected. If it doesn’t for you - then give a proper problem description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello I have solved this issue by following. Hope it will help to others

In httpd.conf (For bitnami server file will be /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf)

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure;SameSite=None
```

Comment: Adding to Dhara's response (because my account is too new to comment) the Apache docs say that the response headers come out of TWO sets of internal tables. Thus "always" is required for some things to work, and an absence of "always" is required for others to work. In my case, Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4.29 I had to remove "always" for the headers to be edited coming out of PHP 7.2. The docs seem to suggest you can have both directives to cover all bases but I have not tested that.

Comment: Don't use this. Hard coding this into your Apache conf or .htaccess will result in incompatible browsers rejecting the cookie completely because they don't understand SameSite=None. You need to sniff the useragent to determine if SameSite=None will work on a particular browser. Google has outlined the process: [https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients)

Answer (score 0):

This might also help for someone still struggling, and using PHP >= 7.3.x and using CI 3.1.11

In the index.php found in the root, add the code below <?php

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"])){
    header('Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID='.$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"].'; SameSite=None');
}
```

It worked for me, after trying it all (in vain)

Answer (score 0):

Paste the code below in your .htaccess file

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !~ /(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 1[0-4]|iPad; CPU OS 1[0-4]|iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 1[0-4]|Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X.*Version\x2F1[0-3].*Safari|Macintosh;.*Mac OS X 10_14.* AppleWebKit.*Version\x2F1[0-3].*Safari)/i">
    Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;SameSite=None;Secure
</If>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

sudo nvim /etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf

`Header set Set-Cookie "mycookie=myvalue; Domain=mydomain.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict"`

sudo systemctl restart apache2

[image: Header set Set-Cookie]